# Why isn't this function executed at include time?

Tags: php

I am including a PHP file and that file should, I think, execute a function when included but it isn't. Can you fill me in why its not executing and how I can make it execute?

```
<?php
// editor.php

if (class_exists('Editor'))
    return;

class Editor {
  public static function initialise() {
    // do some initialisation ...
  }
}

Editor::initialise(); // this function doesn't appear to execute
// Alternate approach: which also doesn't seem to execute
function editor_init() {
    Editor::initialise(); 
}
editor_init();
```

Usage:

```
// Usage
<?php
// main.php

require_once('editor.php'); // here I expect my initialise() function be executed but it isn't.
// Alternate approach
include_once('editor.php'); // here I expect my initialise() function be executed but it isn't.
// Alternate approach
include('editor.php'); // here I expect my initialise() function be executed but it isn't.
```

Comment: There's already a class called `Editor` in existence...

Comment: @Nick, its **never** called. Not even once. My different includes 'methods' are used one at a time and the other methods are commented out.

Comment: Does it work if you get rid of the `class_exists` check? Why do you need that if you use `require_once()`, that will prevent it from being loaded twice.

Comment: @sazr Sorry that comment wasn't particularly useful. The problem is that the file is read, the class defined and then the code interpreted, so `class_exists('Editor')` will always return true because the `Editor` class is defined in the same file (in the same way as you can call a function before you define it in the same file).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are calling `if (class_exists('Editor'))` which returns `true`.

Your `main.php` file should look like:

```
// main.php

if (class_exists('Editor')):
    return;
else:
    require_once('editor.php'); // here I expect my initialise() function be executed but it isn't.
endif;
```

And your `editor.php` file should look like:

```
// editor.php

class Editor {
  public static function initialise() {
    // do some initialisation ...
    echo 'Yes, I am being called.';
  }
}

Editor::initialise();
```